# How do I generate a list URLs on my site linked to by other sites?

Tags: seo, redirects

I'm trying to set up redirects for a clients site.  The issue is that they've taken down the old site so I can't tell what the old URLs were.  Does anyone know of a service or method that can generate a list of all the URLs on my site that are linked to by some site on the internet?  I've tried the backlink checkers, but they only list the links to whatever domain I enter.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that they've taken down the old site so I can't tell what the old URLs were

Assuming the old website was indexed by Google, you can try to search for website in Google's index to see old links. Again, since not much is given regarding timeframe, I am again assuming that the switch has been made recently.

> Does anyone know of a service or method that can generate a list of all the URLs on my site that are linked to by some site on the internet?

Try a combination of the following,

- [Archive.org (Way back machine)](https://archive.org/)
- Simple google search for `site:www.old-domain.com`
- Look into Google webmaster tools
- If there was a sitemap for old domain, then try to look up for a cached version of it in Google search.

Good luck with migrations!